# Sinai and hatred

Tags: commentaries, maseches-shabbos, har-sinai, anti-semitism

What is the exact meaning of this Gemara [[Shabbat 89a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.89a.7?lang=bi)]:

> דרב חסדא ורבה ברי' דרב הונא דאמרי תרווייהו מאי הר סיני הר שירדה שנאה לעכו"ם עליו

It is usually translated as:

> Rav Ḥisda and Rabba, son of Rav Huna, both said: What [is the reason it is called] Mount Sinai? It is because it is a mountain upon which hatred [sina] for the idolaters descended.

Now, some commentators say it talks about the hatred that God and the Jews have towards the idolaters.  But other commentators say it talks about the hatred that the idolaters have towards the Jews.  (In other words, that antisemitism began with the giving of the Torah, because it preached things the gentiles did not want to hear.)

The second is compelling.  But the first is bolstered by what the Gemara says later:

[It was called] the Sinai desert, because hatred descended on it. What was its [real] name? Its name was Horeb… because desolation [hurbah] to idolaters descended on it.  [Shabbat 89b]

So which is it?  Both, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Hatred is more related to a cause in this subject while destruction is a consequence of the hatred.

This idea is all based upon the principle from Shemot Rabbah 12:3, explaining Tehillim 115:16, which says:

> ויאמר ה' אל משה נטה ידך על השמים, הדא הוא דכתיב (תהלים קלה, ו): כל אשר חפץ ה' עשה וגו', **אמר דוד אף על פי שגזר הקדוש ברוך הוא (תהלים קטו, טז): *השמים שמים לה' והארץ נתן לבני אדם*,** משל למה הדבר דומה, למלך שגזר ואמר בני רומי לא ירדו לסוריא ובני סוריא לא יעלו לרומי, **כך כשברא הקדוש ברוך הוא את העולם גזר ואמר: השמים שמים לה' והארץ נתן לבני אדם, כשבקש לתן התורה בטל גזרה ראשונה ואמר *התחתונים יעלו לעליונים והעליונים ירדו לתחתונים*, ואני המתחיל**, שנאמר (שמות יט, כ): וירד ה' על הר סיני, וכתיב (שמות כד, ט): ואל משה אמר עלה אל ה', הרי כל אשר חפץ ה' עשה בשמים ובארץ וגו'.

Prior to the giving of the Torah, there was a limit beyond which, the *Lower Realms* could not challenge and encroach upon the *Upper Realms.* This was due to G-d's original decree from the time of creation (*that the Heavens belong to G-d and the earth belongs to the children of man*) mentioned in the Midrash. That also placed a governor upon the hatred between the two opposites.

When that limit was removed and replaced with a different decree, the hatred increased on both sides.